# Add whole div dynamically on click in angular

Tags: angular

```
   <form class="rounded px-8 pt-6 pb-8 mb-4">
                    <div class="">
                        <div class="mb-4">
                            <label class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2" for="question">
                                Question Name
                            </label>
                            <input
                                class="h-12 shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                                id="question" type="text" placeholder="Enter Question Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-6">
                            <label class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2" for="answer">
                                Answer 1
                            </label>
                            <textarea
                                class="h-20 shadow appearance-none w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight resize border rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                                placeholder="Enter answer here"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex items-center justify-end">
                        <button type="submit"
                            class="bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-700 text-white text-xs lg:text-base font-bold lg:py-2 lg:px-8 py-1 px-6 mr-2 rounded-full uppercase">Add
                            Question</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

I want to add **Question** and **Answer** input fields dynamically on the click of **add question button**. How can we do that?

I used - on div -
id="contentInside" *ngFor="let container of containers"
.TS - this.containers.push(this.containers.length);

But it does not changes the heading of input fields **question** and **answer** to **Question2** and **Answer 2** respectively.

Answer (score 0):

To change the heading of input fields you would need to use the index you're iterating. Try something like this:

```
// Template
...
<div *ngFor="let container of containers; let i = index">
    <label>Question {{ i }}</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Answer {{ i }}">
</div>

// TS
addNewQuestion() {
    this.containers.push({}); // add question properties inside object if needed
}
```